# function to tag different phrases in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function to tag different phrases in a sentence, for eg.:

- due to [word],
- with [word],
- without [word],
- [word] followed by a number,
- number followed by a [word]

I am getting an error message on running the code below:
**sentence=list[w1, w2, ...] for word in w
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

```
 def features(sentence, index):
   sentence=list[w1, w2, ...] 
   index= w[index] for i in w
   return {
            'word': sentence[index], 
            'prefix-1': "due to/due" in sentence[index],
            'prefix-2': "other" in sentence[index],
            'prefix-3': "with" in sentence[index],
            'prefix-4': "without" in sentence[index],
            'is_numeric': sentence[index].isdigit(),
            'prev_word': '' if index == 0 else sentence[index - 1],
            'next_word': '' if index == len(sentence) - 1 else sentence[index + 1],
    }
```

Comment: Please show an actual example of your problem.

Comment: I have updated the post above with an example.

Comment: Where's word coming from if you aren't returning it?? (as per your code)

Comment: That seems to return the correct dictionary; well, except for an extra entry 'word' (thus, you're not showing the actual code you are using). What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Do note that Python will not automatically split 'due to/due' into two options. Instead, the actual phrase to match will have to be "blah blah due to/due blah blah".

Comment: The code I showed before was the actual code I am using. I have updated it with the new code I have tried after your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment yet.

This sounds pretty homeworkish :p
I'm not sure I understand your problem/question, but one thing I definitely noticed.
Might it be, that this `'word': 'c'}` is your unexpected result?
as the docstring of `features` shows `""" sentence: [w1, w2, ...], index: the index of the word """`, you need to call it with a list.

try: `features(['cholera', 'due', 'virus', 'A', '890'], 0)`

or: `features('cholera due virus A 890'.split(), 0)`
you can split a string into a list with space as separator with the `split` method.

```
l ='cholera due virus A 890'.split()
l == ['cholera', 'due', 'virus', 'A', '890'] # is True
```